# Jenkins Multi configuration job: Skip build step if slave is offline

Tags: jenkins

I have created a Jenkins Multi configuration job that runs a build step on 5 windows slaves. Now if one of the slaves is offline (for some reason) the job is blocked until the slave(s) which is offline is put back online.

Is it possible to continue the build and simply skip the build step on the slave(s) that is offline?

Comment: You can [abort the build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin) if it takes longer than X minutes. I'm currently trying this out, so I don't know if that will stop the configuration or the entire job.

Comment: Using "Build-timeout+Plugin" does not kill the job after X minutes, since it has not started yet (it's only in queue). I've opened a feature request on the matrix-project plugin, to skip offline nodes (as in elastic axis): https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29380 . Please up-vote it.

Answer (score 5):

Try using [Elastic Axis](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Elastic+Axis) plugin. 
Afer installing it, in the multi configuration job you can find new axis added as Elastic axis. You just need to provide the label of the node. The job will run on all the nodes with that label. There is a check box provided to skip the nodes that are offline.